# PHP forgot user password

Tags: php

I have two pages one in which has a modal with a link at the bottom for "forget password" this should then carry the users email from the form and pass this into my second page, where an email is then constructed and sent to the user with a randomly generated password.

index.php

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="Login" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1> Sign up </h1>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <section class="container">
          <div id="login-form">
            <form method="post">
              <table align="center" width="30%" border="0">
                <tr>
                  <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" required /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><input type="password"  class="form-control" name="pass" placeholder="Your Password" required /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><button type="submit" name="btn-login" class="btn btn-default">Sign In</button> 
                </tr>
              </table>
            </form>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <tr>
        <td><a href="register.php">Sign Up Here  |  </a></td>
        <td><a href="forgetpassword.php">Forgot Password</a></td>
      </tr>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

forgetpassword.php

```
 <?php

    include('dbConnection.php');

    if (isset($_POST['email'])){ 

        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $new_password = substr(str_shuffle(abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ),0,1) . substr(str_shuffle(aBcDeFgHiJkLmNoPqRsTuVwXyZ0123456789),0,15);
        $query = "SELECT `email` FROM `users` WHERE `email` ='".$email1."'";

        if (mysqli_num_rows ($result = mysqli_query($con, $query)) > 0){
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

            $email = $row['email'];
            $hashpass = hash ("sha256", $new_password); //hashing the password

            $query1 = "UPDATE `users` SET `pass` = '".$hashpass."' WHERE `email` = '".$email."'";

            $result1 = mysqli_query($con, $query1);

            if ($email == ""){
                echo "<script type ='text/javascript'>alert('Re-type your email address and try again!');</script>";
            }

            $to = $email;
            $subject = "Change your password";
            $message = "Below is your new password \r\n\r\n " 
            .$newpassword. "Thanks";
            $headers = "From: saracassells@gmail.com";
            $mail = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        }
    }

    ?>
```

my error appears to be with the line `if (isset($_POST['email']))`as when an echo is placed before this it is displayed, but after is not.  Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on for your php code ?

Comment: @Maximus2012 No, pretty new to PHP so not sure on how to do this...

Comment: You really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Based on what you're saying `$_POST`['email']` is not set because you're not passing anything to your PHP

Comment: @JayBlanchard I have entered in data to the input field on the index page for this field, so it is set?

Comment: You're not sending it as form data to forgetpassword.php. Do you have a form for that?

Comment: *"with a randomly generated password"* - Bad practice. You need to setup/generate a unique token where they can choose their own password, then delete that key on verification/success.

Comment: How are you posting the form? Ajax? Form post? Where is the form posting to? I noticed a </script> tag at the bottom of index.php. Why is that there? Do you have some javascript you are not showing us?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing quotes around the str_shuffle() calls.

```
$new_password = substr(str_shuffle('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'),0,1) . substr(str_shuffle('aBcDeFgHiJkLmNoPqRsTuVwXyZ0123456789'),0,15);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-shuffle.php

Comment: PHP may think it is a constant and give a NOTICE, ie. `E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Use of undefined constant abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ - assumed 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' -- at line 2
E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Use of undefined constant aBcDeFgHiJkLmNoPqRsTuVwXyZ0123456789 - assumed 'aBcDeFgHiJkLmNoPqRsTuVwXyZ0123456789' -- at line 2` but then assumes not and quotes it, giving a return: `r2Dq4emsH5Xo1F6u` for example. Her other problem, which she states clearly, is `$_POST[email']` is not set.

Comment: Those notices will cause issues if this is an ajax post.

Comment: True, but I don't think we can assume AJAX and if error reporting in PHP is set not to display the notices will only be sent to the error logs.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `Forgot Password` link is simply just a href link. So its just going to redirect the user to that page. But since you are looking for the `email` attribute to be set in the post data, nothing is going to be done within that conditional block.

There are probably lots of ways to do this. You could prompt the user for their email address on the `forgotpassword.php` page, then have that input in a form that submits again to the same page, therefore including the email in the post data like you are expecting.